# How to show a Page inside MainWindow?

Tags: wpf

In my MainWindow.xaml, I have a DockPanel that contains Menu, Page and Status Bar. I want to show this Page when an option is clicked from the Menu. The Page should appear as centered to the parent, MainWindow. This Page will be acting as a center place to show different Forms, i.e, User Controls, Content etc..

I am not following how to add a reference in the Code-Behind .cs file of the MainWindow to show this Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most things that I want to Disappear/Reappear, I set the visibililty.  If you are using the codebehind for this, ensure that the page has a name:

```
<Page x:Name="MyPage"/>
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
This.MyPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Unless your page is a resource,  If that is the case, just:

```
This.FindResouce("MyPage");
```

Out of curiosity, why do you want to use a page? I have never had cause to use one and would like to know what one needs it for.

Comment: I want the MainWindow to act as an MDI and in the child pages I want to show screens when the user selects an option from the menu.

Comment: Ahh.  I have done a single MDI app before, but I built mine as spawnable views in a custom ItemsControl based on a listbox.